# XPath statement to assign an integer variable to the position() function in a powershell script

Tags: xpath, powershell-2.0

I am working on a Powershell script which takes as input an XML file, searches for inner text associated with a specific element/tag in that xml file, and returns the position of that element/tag, if it exists, so that the position of that element can be used to replace the inner text with some other data.  For example, there may be an xml file that looks like the following . . .

```
<root>
    <category>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <vegetable>broccoli</vegetable>
        <fruit>pear</fruit>
        <vegetable>brussel sprouts</vegetable>
        <fruit>orange</fruit>
    </category>
</root>
```

So, let's say that in one part of my Powershell script I have some code to find the inner text, "orange".  I would like to store in a variable the "position" integer of the "fruit" element that contains "orange" as it's inner text.  So, in the above xml file, the position integer would be 3 (or 2 if starting at base zero).  How would I write a proper XPath statement to access this 3rd "fruit" location through a variable?  Maybe I want to access this location so that I can change "orange" to "banana" or something.  I have tried the following with no success . . .

$orangePosition = ??? (I assigned a value of 3 for testing purposes)

root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::category/fruit[position()=$orangePosition]")

I have seen where "position() is assigned an integer value.  I want to use a variable in place of the integer because I don't know what index in a particular file the inner text "orange" may be.  Is this even possible?  I've seen other posts that question similar issues, but none of them seem to work when I apply the solution (if there is one stated) to a powershell script).  Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: You are making the fundamental mistake of imagining that position() returns the position of a node among its siblings. That's not what it does. Furthermore, in XPath 1.0 the only useful place to use position() is within a predicate, which means that it cannot be the result of the expression.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand your first statement.  I do realize that my understanding of what "position()" actually does is probably not correct.  That is why I am asking the question and attempting to clarify.

Comment: I don't really understand the second part of your statement.  You state that the only useful place to use "position()" is within a predicate.

Comment: From everything I have read about XPath and predicates, this is exactly what I have done.  Predicates are the portion of the XPath statement in square brackets, correct?  So when I write a path that includes "category/fruit[position()=<INSERT NUMBER HERE>]", from every example I have ever seen, this is the correct format for including position() within the confines of a predicate, is it not?  Can you further explain or refer me to a resource that I can understand for clarification.  I am not an expert using XPath so any info you can direct me towards would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's useful to use position() in a predicate. But then you select nodes whose position satisfies the predicate, which doesn't do what you asked for, which is to return the position itself.

Comment: Thank you Micheal Kay.  I believe I understand you now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `root.SelectNodes("//category/fruit[. = 'orange']/preceding-sibling::fruit).Count + 1`. If you want to do it with XPath alone then use the `Evaluate` method e.g. `root.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(//category/fruit[. = 'orange']/preceding-sibling::fruit) + 1")`. That should return a C# `double` value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was making this harder than it needed to be.  After extensive research, I have learned that there is really no need to use an index/position integer at all.  I can achieve exactly what I need by doing the following . . .

root.SelectNodes('//categories/fruit') | Where-Object {$*.InnerText.Contains('orange')} | foreach {$*.InnerText -eq 'banana'}

But, I can still think of cases where I might want to actually know the index of the element I would like to edit so that I can exclude other, similar elements that may contain the same innertext.  Anyway, this works good enough for my purposes right now.  Thanks to all who responded and attempted to help.